# How to prevent a subclass inherit a static method in the super class

Tags: java, subclass, inheritance

Considering some security issues, I don't want the subclass inherit the static method from its super class,not even call this method,  how can I do this? Please help!

Comment: Given that the superclass will be in the classpath and the method in question is static I don't think that will help security very much...

Comment: All you'd have to do is upcast your subclass instance to its parent class and you'd get the static method you don't want inherited, so this whole scenario seems no bueno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static methods are not inherited in the same sense as instance methods are.  If you declare a static method as public (or package private) it is accessible whether or not there is a local redeclaration in a child class.  The local redeclaration merely means that the child class has to qualify the name of the method; e.g.

```
public class Parent {
    public static void foo() { ... }
}

public class Child {
    public static void foo() { ... }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo();  // calls local override
        Parent.foo(); // calls original version.
}
```

If you don't want the `Child` class to be able to call the `Parent.foo` method, then you need to declare it as `private` (or maybe package private if `Child` and `Parent` are in different packages.)

But even then, if the `Child` class has permission to use reflection, then it can easily use that to call a `private` method in the `Parent` class.  So unless you are sandboxing your code Java access modifiers are not a security mechanism.

Comment: +1. "Static methods are not inherited in the same sense as instance methods are"

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the super class, don't you just make the method in question private?

Answer (score 2):

Since a static method is basically floating code that can live anywhere, move the method to another (utility) class

Answer (score 1):

Override the signature to do nothing.

Comment: This doesn't help ... because the child class can still call the "overridden" method directly.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want your method is only accessable to your parent class you
   have to make your method as private
2. If the method has to limit access with in a package you have to make
   it as defaul(No Access modifiers ) Eg:

   ```
    void hello(){
   }
   ```

   Even if a sub class cannot access this method Outside the package (But keep in mind that a subclass in same package can access this method )

Hope this helps .....

Comment: But beware that it declaring a method `private` only prevents calls from regular Java code.  If you can use reflection, you can call private methods in other classes ... as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want your sub-class to inherit any of the methods of the super-class,make the method in super-class **private**.

For example

> Class Parent{
>
> private void foo(){
>
> }
>
> }
>
> class Child extends Parent{
>
> }

In this scenario as the visibility level is private, the child class would not even have the visibility on the existence of a method named foo() in super class as it never had been inherited.